# LocalDate field is coming blank in xml response

Tags: xml, rest, spring-boot, java-8, jersey

I am creating simple spring boot application with Jersey REST to return list of messages object which has Id, message, created(LocalDate) and author.

The created field which is Java 8 LocalDate type is coming blank in the xml response. It is coming well populated when I return JSON response. 
DemoBean -

```
@XmlRootElement
public class DemoBean {

    private long id;
    private String message;
    private LocalDate created;
    private String author;

    public DemoBean(){

    }

    public DemoBean(long id, String message, LocalDate created, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.created = created;
        this.author = author;
    }
```

Endpoint -

```
@GET
    @Path("/messages")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<DemoBean> getDemo(@QueryParam("message") String message){
        log.info("getDemo() - START");

        return demoService.getAllDemoBeans();
    }
```

XML Response -

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <demoBeans>
>     <demoBean>
>         <author>xyz</author>
>         <created/>
>         <id>1</id>
>         <message>Hey there!</message>
>     </demoBean>
```

Why created field is coming blank ? What needs to be done here? please help.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason here is that for `LocalDate` there is no `XmlAdapter` defined out of the box; so you have to introduce your own one.

For example you can:

1. Define your adapter for `LocalDate`:

   ```
   package us.atamai.service;

   import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
   import java.time.LocalDate;

   public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {

       public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
           return LocalDate.parse(v);
       }

       public String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception {
           return v.toString();
       }

   }
   ```
2. And mark the getter with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`:

   ```
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
   public LocalDate getCreated() {
       return created;
   }
   ```

---

After that you will have next output:

```
<demoBeans>
    <demoBean>
        <author>author1</author>
        <created>2018-09-19</created>
        <id>1</id>
        <message>message1</message>
    </demoBean>
    <demoBean>
        <author>author2</author>
        <created>2018-09-20</created>
        <id>2</id>
        <message>message2</message>
    </demoBean>
</demoBeans>
```